# Millis() Function with Relay Connected to Motor

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, motor, relay

I connected my motor to a relay module and everything is working fine, but the timer that I created is what is causing trouble. What I wish to achieve is for my motor to activate after 5 seconds of the light being on and stay on until the photoresistor no longer detects light. It is able to achieve that, but after a few trials, the relay activates as soon as the photoresistor detects light. I can temporarily fix this by pressing the reset button, but again after a few trials, it is the same again.

I have provided a video:
https://youtu.be/XmRjOIuPIRc

```
int analogValue;
int voltage;
int timer = millis();
void setup()
{
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  analogValue = analogRead(A0);
  analogWrite(7, voltage);
  if(analogValue > 200){
    if((millis() - timer) >10000){
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    }
  }
      else{
        timer = millis();
       digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      }
}
```

Comment: how big is an int in this compiler? Consider the possibility of overflow.

Comment: Like the max number for an int? It is an arduino uno, so it should be 16 bit. I will try to declare timer as unsigned long and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

As Brian Drummond correctly suspected, this is an integer overflow issue.

On the ATmega Arduino, an `int` is a 16 bit signed type which will overflow in just over 32 seconds.

As a result, the `millis()` function instead returns an `unsigned long` which will overflow in 49.7 days.

If you change the type of "timer" to `unsigned long` then things will work in the short term.

Additionally, because you performed a subtraction *before* comparison, they will even work in the overflow/wraparound case, because you'll still end up with a valid time *difference* to compare against your threshold of 10000.

At first glance one might think that you existing code would be similarly wraparound safe, too.  But it isn't, because the math of wraparounds doesn't work right between an `unsigned long` and a (signed) `int`.

Additionally it probably has no bearing on your issue, the following line of code serves no useful purpose and should be removed:

```
analogWrite(7, voltage);
```

Comment: Right, thank you. I originally had analogWrite(7, voltage); there because I had a serial monitor for my photoresistor, but I removed it.

Comment: I can see why it would be confusing but `analogWrite()` sets a PWM output, it doesn't generate serial messages.  For that you want `Serial.println(voltage)` as in the Analog Read Serial example sketch mentioned in response to your first version of this question yesterday.

Comment: Ohh ok I see, thank you.

Comment: Good catch ....

Answer (score 2):

Had to change int to unsigned long.